# Roku SceneGraph with Search Functionality

Tags: search, roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I'm creating a Roku app in SceneGraph and trying to near duplicate the search functionality I had using the old SDK.  I'm stuck at only being able to display the mini keyboard.  I'm trying to add buttons via buttongroup (i.e., Search, Cancel) but having two issues:

1. Not sure how to get the text string that's typed into the mini keyboard and store that in a variable or field so I can perform the search on it.
2. How to create a Search button and give it focus when user is ready to search for the string they entered.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SGDEX (Scenegraph Developer Extensions) is what you need.  They have a view called "SearchView".  Look it up.

Also...

RALE (Roku Advanced Layout Editor) has good search options. - I have been unable to find a decent Search sample.  It would be cool if we could export the  source code from RALE.

However if you haven't tried RALE. You could upload your script, then add search to it.